# How do we plan this multi-city and multi-country trip to be least expensive?

Tags: air-travel, budget, tickets

Situation : Buddy in US on H1B. Indian citizen. Recently got his Australian PR and has to go to Australia to validate his (and his spouses (ooh I love the dal!))visa. It is sufficient if he just passes through one of the airports in AU. Can take the next flight out. Birmingham, AL is his closest airport in USA. 
Costs : Round trip tickets from BHM to SYD/MEL cost about USD 3700 per pax -> $7200. However, since he is yet to take his vacation(17 days) this year if he goes to IN for some family time the round trip tickets from BHM to HYD (Hyderabad, his town in India) cost about $1700 per head -> USD 3400. Round trip Tickets from HYD to SYD are $2000 for the couple (It seems a touch and go is all they want in AU) => 3400+2000 = $5400 for the trip from USA to IN and AU.

It seems to me that the travels costing $5400 are his best shot at the least expensive travel. Multi city search on kayak (HYD-SYD-BHM) returns very expensive airfare($3600 per passenger). Are we overlooking anything ? Do any of y'all know of any other options this guy could take ? Any airfare websites we should particularly take a look at ?The main objective is to have the least expensive tour from BHM and a touch and go in any airport in AU.

Comment: What about a "half way round the world" ticket? (Like a round the world, but number of continents constrained to just do US/Asia/Australasia)

Comment: Isn't this a flight shopping question? The kind that should be asked on FlightFox rather than here?

Comment: @Gagravarr I couldnt have thought this would come under the half way round the world. From a quick google I am reading this to understand it better : http://intransit.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/04/13/pros-and-cons-of-an-around-the-world-ticket/?_r=0 Anyplace else I could search/read more about what you are suggesting ?

Comment: @hippietrail Have you used that site before ? Is it worth the time and money ? I am not particularly sure if my buddy would spend $24 or more :) I will sure swing this by him

Comment: @happybuddha: No I haven't used it, but our #1 contributor MarkMayo swears by it and recommends it all over our site.

Comment: @happybuddha For OneWorld, it'd be covered by the [Circle Pacific ticket](http://www.oneworld.com/flights/multi-continent-fares/circle-pacific), which is one of the various "half way round the world" tickets that exist (though they tend to have special names). You *don't* want a RTW ticket for this thought! Needs to be one centred on just part of the world